# Is there a correct, yet short way to turn a JSON array with strings into one string?

Tags: postgresql

I want to turn a JSON array with a bunch of strings into one string. Following is not a JSON array, but the expected result for `['a', 'b']` and works:

```
select array_to_string(array['a', 'b'], ',');

 array_to_string 
═════════════════
 a,b
```

This does not work:

```
select array_to_string('{"key": ["a", "b"]}'::json ->> 'key', ',');
```

Then I found [this](https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/08/postgresql-9-4-how-to-convert-json-array-elements-into-string-array-jsonb_array_elements-string_agg/):

```
select
    string_agg(_, ',')
from 
    json_array_elements_text('{"key": ["a", "b"]}'::json -> 'key') as _;
```

This works, but also looks like it cannot be the best solution. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: What version of PG do you use? If it's 9.3 or less then you have a lot fewer JSON functions available to you.

Comment: I use 11.1 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT` to expand it to a set of TEXT values, then `STRING_AGG` them.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(j, ',')
FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT('{"key": ["a", "b"]}'::JSON->'key') AS j
```

The bit with the `TRIM` you posted in your question was required in 9.3 and lower because `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT` was not available in those versions.

If you want a single function solution, you could always wrap the above query in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_array_to_text(json_array JSON)
    RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
    SELECT STRING_AGG(j, ',')
    FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(json_array) AS j;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Then you just call the function with the array: `SELECT json_array_to_text('{"key": ["a", "b"]}'::JSON->'key')`

And get: `a,b`

Comment: Thanks, but I've updated my question. Even using `json_array_elements_text` this looks like throwing a book to turn of TV.

Comment: Ok, but that's the only or at least the best way there is at the moment, as far as I'm aware. As I said, you can just create a function which takes a json array and returns a string, and put the query in there so you don't have to type it out every time.

Comment: @marcus Added sample function