# facing 'malformed array literal' when trying to insert json in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I'm trying to pass a json object from my python code with psycopg2 like this to a postgres stored procedure:

```
{
  "experience": null,
  "phoneNumber": [
    "091184xxx"
  ],
  "location": "tehran"
}
```

but this error occur:

> ERROR: malformed array literal: "phoneNumbers" Detail: Array value
>   must start with "{" or dimension information.

how can I fix this error?

UPDATE:
here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data(job_req JSONB)
  RETURNS VOID
AS $$
DECLARE

INSERT INTO "JobRequirements" (expertise,"phoneNumbers", "location")
  VALUES (
    job_req ->> 'expertise',
    job_req ->> 'phoneNumbers' :: VARCHAR [],
    job_req ->> 'location'
  );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and type of "phoneNumbers" column is `varchar(255) []`

Comment: Show us the insert query that runs from the procedure and the definition of the table being inserted.

Comment: i've been add them to question

Comment: [I think you need to do sth. like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560358/is-there-a-correct-yet-short-way-to-turn-a-json-array-with-strings-into-one-str). If so, yes, it is lame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must extract the JSON array element as a text and convert it to a `VARCHAR` array before inserting.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data(job_req JSONB)
  RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "JobRequirements" (expertise,"phoneNumbers", "location")
  SELECT 
    job_req ->> 'expertise' ,
     array_agg(d.phonenumber::VARCHAR ) ,
    job_req ->> 'location' 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(job_req->'phoneNumbers') as d(phonenumber);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=71d96aae51acc88aabeedaefc9b3d32b)